# Same html form in two places on the same page

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to place this code in two different places on an html page and have it submit properly regardless of which box the user types the phrase:

```
<form id="search_form" action="http://example.com/search/results/" method="get">
    <label for="search"></label>

    <input autocomplete="off" id="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" type="text">

    <button type="submit" title="Search">
        <span><span>Search</span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

The problem:

If there are two forms then the first form submits this way:

```
/search/results/?q=test&q=
```

Which fails.

The second form submits this way:

```
/search/results/?q=&q=test
```

And works but is incorrect.

How can I rewrite the forms to make each one unique so that the search button next to each input makes either form submit like this:

```
/search/results/?q=test
```

Comment: Make sure you have unique ID and name values and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Which browser are you testing this in?

Comment: @all I found the problem. The form wasn't properly closed out so the initial form was carrying into the next form. Renaming the ids works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each form needs a unique id.

```
<form id="search_form1" action="http://example.com/search/results/" method="get">
    <label for="search"></label>

    <input autocomplete="off" id="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" type="text">

    <button type="submit" title="Search">
        <span><span>Search</span></span>
    </button>
</form>

<form id="search_form2" action="http://example.com/search/results/" method="get">
    <label for="search"></label>

    <input autocomplete="off" id="search" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" type="text">

    <button type="submit" title="Search">
        <span><span>Search</span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just make form inputs the same, and submit only one form.

```js
$('input[type=text]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[type=text]').val($(this).val()); 
})
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault()
  $('#form2').submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="form1">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="textbox" placeholder="form2">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```